# Javascript, setInterval starts after while loop? how to make it start inside while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, alert, setinterval

I have a piece of javascript:

```
<script>
  var i=1;
  while(i<10){
    setInterval(function(){
      alert(i);
    },1);
    i++;
  }
</script>
```

It alerted number 10 instead of number 1 to 10.  I expect `setInterval` to alert number 1 to 10 and keep alert from 1 to 10.

Comment: I'm almost certain you want that to be 'setTimeout'. That loop creates ten alerts every millisecond!

Comment: @Grim... - got that right, I didn't notice and tried a fiddle, and the results where..... wait for it ..... it never stopped and couldn't close the browser window.

Comment: @Blam - of course they do, my browser didn't crash, I was just making a point that it would be almost an endless queue of alerts.

Comment: how do i make it alert from 1 to 10 and continue to start all over again and again? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, but is this what you wanted?

```
setInterval(function(){
  var i=1;
  while(i<=10){
    alert(i);
    i++;
  }
 },1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are closures and scope :

```
<script>
   var i=1;
   while(i<10){
      (function(j) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert(j);
          },1);
      })(i);

      i++;
   }
</script>
```

In short, the while loop finishes before the value of `i` can be alerted.
Also not the order, or lack thereof in the fiddle :

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYPJs/)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you are asking the computer to run the nested inner function once per millisecond.  And you are asking this to be done ten times in a row, so by the end, the computer should be sending an alert exactly ten thousand times per second.  I'm surprised it doesn't consume all the CPU and consume all memory and cause a fatal error.

This will continue until you call `clearInterval()`, or until the window is closed.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: how do i make it alert from 1 to 10 and continue to start all over again and again? Thanks

Comment: For followup questions please post your question on yahoo answers.